# Iterar informacion interna de un Map<Key,Value>

Tags: java, mongodb, spring, map, iteradores

por favor estoy haciendo una practica con MongoDB y Spring pero tengo el siguiente dilema; en la DB tengo la siguiente información:

```
{
  "menu":"querys",
  "optionsList":[
     {
        "options":[
           "0001",
           "0022",
           "0014",
           "0041",
           "0042",
           "0043"
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

La estructura del objeto en Java esta de la siguiente manera:

```
@Document(collection = "menu")
public class GetAllRules implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7375796948388333325L;

@JsonProperty(value = "menu")
private String name;

@JsonProperty(value = "optionsList")
private List<Map<String, ?>> optionsList;

//Getters and Setters.
```

Con este método obtengo el JSON (estoy utilizando el MongoRepository), con el primer FOR obtengo toda la información y con el segundo obtengo el mapa interior, pero no se como lograr iterar la información que se encuentra a dentro de **options** les agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar con el tema:

```
public String obtener() {

    List<GetAllRules> allRules = iGetMenuService.getAll(); // Lista de Mongo

    String key= "options";
    
    for (GetAllRules rules : allRules) {
        for (Map<String, ?> internal : rules.getOptionsList()) {
            System.out.println(internal);
            }
    
        }
    
    return "finalizado";
}
```